# Pointers exit code 6

Tags: c, pointers, exit-code

Well i m struggling with the pointers, why doesn t work the function biggest in the end (yes of that s dummy function)? (exit code 6)
Ty for help

code:

```
int search(int const a[], int n, int key) {

    for (int *i = a; i < a + n; i++) {
        if ( key == *i ) return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void print_row(int const a[], int n, int row) {

    for (int *i = a + n * row; i < a + n * (row + 1); i++) {
        printf("%d  ", *i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void biggest(double x, long *int_part, double *frac_part) {

    *int_part = (long) x;
    *frac_part = x - *int_part;
}

main () {

    int tempretures[7][24];

    for (int *i = &tempretures[0][0]; i < &tempretures[7][24]; i++) {
        static int j = 1;
        *i = j;
        j+=2;
    }
    tempretures[6][5] = 32;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", tempretures[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Is it: %d\n", search(tempretures, 7*24, 32));
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        print_row(tempretures, 24, i);
    }
    long a = 0; double b = 0;
    biggest(5.67, &a, &b);
    printf("%li", a);
}
```

Comment: `int tempretures[7][24];` last element is `tempretures[6][23]`. So next of last elements is `tempretures[6][24]`

Comment: I missed that out really, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int *i = &tempretures[0][0]; i < &tempretures[7][24]; i++) {
    static int j = 1;
    *i = j;
    j+=2;
}
```

This runs *way* past the end of the array, stopping only when it hits every element of row number 7, but there is no row number 7.